# How do i run a node specific function on button click

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm trying to change the context of a text file on an HTML button click.
I have this so far:

**index.html**:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Table</title>
    <script src="node-main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <embed src="table.txt">
    <button onclick="Update()">Update</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**node-main.js**:

```
const fs = require('fs');

function Update() {
    fs.writeFileSync("table.txt", 'New text');
}
```

It does not do what I was expecting.
It gives me the error:**`require is not defined`**

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You may need to go back to basics - it looks like you are mixing up server-side and client-side functionality? What i would expect is that on click, it would make an AJAX call to the server that would then do whatever file modifications you need...

Comment: and how would I do that?

Comment: @SquigglyHI I updated my answer. You need a server. Then you need to make fetch requests to your (Express) server from your client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run node-main.js as a server that receives fetch requests from your client. You're trying to run server-side scripts on the client.

Try using Express.js

https://expressjs.com/

Comment: I just fixed it by using express and nodemon, so thank you :)